# Wordpress 3.6: Nested Jquery Dialog Overlay

Tags: wordpress

I have two jquery dialog nested. I am getting separate overlay with separate z-index when "modal" is true. But in wordpress 3.6 i am getting same overlay and ui-dialog z-index with both dialogs.

Is it a bug of wordpress 3.6 jquery-ui-dialog library?

Comment: Seeing what I'm guessing is a similar z-index issue with modal dialogs in 3.6. In my case however dialog is not nested, but the dialog itself is modal with no escape but back-button, while the css is off causing a misalignment of the dialog's X image with the close button in the dialog header.
Could be a discussion better suited to the [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) forum?
Meanwhile, your description of the behavior is somewhat ambiguous (IMHO) and might benefit from a little clarification.

Comment: Just confirmed this issue is caused by fact that WP 3.6 now uses jQuery 1.10 (whereas 3.5x used 1.9.1) See discussion [HERE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/lots-of-jquery-and-jquery-ui-conflicts-in-wp-36)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments state, it seems to be an issue with WP using jQuery 1.10.
An ugly quickfix could be to add "dialogClass   : 'wp-dialog'," to the dialogsettings.

Like this example:

```
$("#idofmodaldialog").dialog({
dialogClass   : 'wp-dialog'}
```

This makes the dialog work, but it's not pretty.